# Swift IAP restoreCompletedTransactions restores even non purchased items

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have 4 non-consumables in my application and the purchasing of these works without any problems.

However, I have created a restorePurchases button which restores all products regardless of whether the user has purchased them or not. I've tested this on 4 different sand box test users, and the results are consistent (i.e. for a test user who has never bought the non consumables, clicking 'restore' restores all products)

My restore code looks like:

```
@IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    print("transactions restored")

    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "productAbc1":
            defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "productAbc1")

        case "productAbc2":
            defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "productAbc2")

        case "productAbc3":
            defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "productAbc3")

        case "productAbc3":
            defaults.setBool(true , forKey: "productAbc4")

        default:
            print("IAP not setup; enable it")
        }

    }
}
```

Do I need to be checking additional parameters in paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished? Comparing my code to many other similar questions / IAP examples, it looks pretty much the same. Is this an issue with the sandbox environment or code?

Comment: Have you tried printing out those transactions to see what is actually contained?

Comment: Depending on the test user I restore with, the console prints a multiple amounts of each prodID (5-15 per prodID) - even with a brand new test user that hasn't previously purchased anything...

Comment: Ahhh man. As I typed that response, it came to me...I simply hadn't included `queue.finishTransaction(transaction)` for each case... All sorted now! Thanks for helping me get the cogs grinding :) ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
```

for each case was missing; meaning they were never clearing from the queue. So the next time I attempted to restore the purchases, all previous transactions were found (and restoring).

Adding the above line of code resolved the issue.